# How can I make a class in C# that I can initialize just like a string?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to be able to initialize a class just like I initialize a string:

```
string str = "hello";
MyClass class = "hello";
```

I really don't know what exactly `string str = "hello";` does. I assume `"hello"` gets translated by the compiler into `new System.String("hello");` but I'm not sure. Maybe is just not possible or maybe I'm missing something very elemental; if that's the case excuse my ignorance :). What I'm trying to make is a class that works just like a string but stores the string in a file automatically.

Ok, here's my code after reading you answers:

```
class StringOnFile
{
    private static string Extension = ".htm";
    private string _FullPath;
    public bool Preserve = false;

    public string FullPath
    {
        get
        {
            return _FullPath;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator StringOnFile(string value)
    {
        StringOnFile This = new StringOnFile();
        int path = 0;

        do{
            path++;
            This._FullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path.ToString() + Extension);
        } 
        while(File.Exists(This._FullPath));

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(This._FullPath))
        {
            sw.Write(value);
        }

        return This;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(StringOnFile stringOnFile)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(stringOnFile._FullPath))
        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    ~StringOnFile()
    {
        if(!Preserve) File.Delete(FullPath);
    }
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: Oh, and by the way, is there any way to make the code inside a non code sentence (I'm talking about this forum now) (like the code "hello" inside the sentence "I assume "hello" gets translated..." in my question) have colors just like the two lines of code in my question?

Comment: "I assume `"hello"` gets translated by the compiler into new `System.String("hello")`" -- no, string literals are built into .NET runtime at a very low level. `"hello"` in C# corresponds to a `ldstr "hello"` instruction in the IL.

Comment: So we could say the string class have a implicit conversion to a ldstr (I assume that's a pointer to a memeory block containing a string)? I'm just trying to make sense out of this. Want to figure out what's the general rule, unless there is no general rule for `string str = "somthing";` and what the compliler does on that case it only does it for that case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following

```
class MyClass {
    public static implicit operator MyClass(string value) {
        // Custom logic here 
        return new MyClass();
    }
}

void Example() {
  MyClass v1 = "data";
}
```

This will get the end result you are looking for.  However I would advise against this approach.  There are several pitfalls with implicit conversions that you will eventually run into.  Much better to just have a constructor which takes the `string`

Comment: Or a static method, of course - which can be more informative as to the expected meaning of the string: `FromName` etc. That also allows multiple methods with the same parameters but different meanings.

Comment: +1 for the final advice: it's better and clearer to have a ctor that takes a string, but use it only when it makes sense semantically, i.e., the string should be a vital needed part in *constructing* the object.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you *can* create an implicit conversion from string to your type... but I would personally rarely do so. One example of a class that *does* is `XNamespace` from LINQ to XML. Does your class *really* just have a string member? If so, maybe it's suitable. Or maybe it only has a string and some other fields which can usually be defaulted... but in *most* cases, I wouldn't expect a conversion from `string` to be appropriate.

To put it another way: should your users really think of your class in exactly the same way as a string? Is it effectively a wrapper around a string? If you could give us more details, we could give more advice.

And no, the compiler *doesn't* translate "hello" into `new System.String("hello")` - that would just cause a recursive problem, of course, as well as breaking interning. IL has direct support for string constants, which the C# compiler uses.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement implicity conversion from string http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(VS.71).aspx